# Why we enclose value of variable in parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I have seen multiple nodejs examples where

```
var minute = (new Date() ). getMinutes();
```

is defined like that. Why is this date object in parenthesis when

```
var minute = new Date().getMinutes();
```

works

Comment: Personal choice, probably. There's no other reason to wrap this particular example in parentheses aside from preference.

Comment: To make it instantly readable for people who aren't sure if the version without parenthesis would be interpreted like that, or like `new (Date().getMinutes())`.

Comment: I think @Paulpro has the right idea there. It's not ambiguous here but you can write `new Date;` without parentheses if there are no arguments, and in that situation `new Date.getMinutes()` would actually be understood by the parser as `new (Date.getMinutes())` which is wrong.

Comment: It's all about readability and most importantly, order of operations. Remember `PEMDAS`, parenthesis are given priority when deciding how an expression should be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` keyword could be ambiguous (to a human) without the parentheses. i.e. is it a new `Date()` or is it a new `Date().getMinutes()`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets test it:

```
// let there be
function someclass()
{
    console.log("constructor"); 
    this.method = function()
    {
       console.log("method");
    }
}

// Trying to call different versions

new test().method()
// Output:
// constructor
// method

(new test()).method()
// Output:
// constructor
// method


// just to be sure:
new Date().getTime() === (new Date()).getTime()
// Output:
true
```

As shown here and mentioned by others, there is no semantic need for the parentheses.